# Pydantic V2 - @field_validator `values` argument equivalent

Tags: python, pydantic

I'm migrating from v1 to v2 of Pydantic and I'm attempting to replace all uses of the deprecated @validator with @field_validator.

Previously, I was using the `values` argument to my validator function to reference the values of other previously validated fields. As the [v1 docs say](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/validators/#field-checks):

> You can also add any subset of the following arguments to the signature (the names must match):
>
> - values: a dict containing the name-to-value mapping of any previously-validated fields

It seems this `values` argument is no longer passed as the `@field_validator` signature has [changed](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/migration/#changes-to-validators-allowed-signatures). However, the migration docs don't mention a `values` equivalent in v2 and the v2 validator documentation page has not yet been updated for v2.0.

Does anyone know the preferred approach for v2?

V1 validator:

```py
@validator('password2')
def passwords_match(cls, v, values, **kwargs):
    if 'password1' in values and v != values['password1']:
        raise ValueError('passwords do not match')
    return v
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The current version of the Pydantic v2 documentation is actually up to date for the [field validators](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.6/concepts/validators/#field-validators) section in terms of what the signature of your validation method must/can look like.

> - the second argument is the field value to validate; it can be named as you please
> - the third argument is an instance of `pydantic.ValidationInfo`
>
> [...]
>
> If you want to access values from another field inside a `@field_validator`, this may be possible using `ValidationInfo.data`, which is a dict of field name to field value. Validation is done in the order fields are defined, so you have to be careful when using `ValidationInfo.data` to not access a field that has not yet been validated/populated [...]

(Side note: You can look up a bit more information about the `ValidationData` protocol in the [Pydantic Core API reference](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.6/api/pydantic_core_schema/#pydantic_core.core_schema.ValidationInfo), although it is a bit terse and could do with some cross-references.)

---

### The old way (v1)

Say you had the following code in Pydantic v1:

```py
from typing import Any

from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError, validator


class UserModel(BaseModel):
    ...
    password1: str
    password2: str

    @validator("password2")
    def passwords_match(cls, v: str, values: dict[str, Any]) -> str:
        if "password1" in values and v != values["password1"]:
            raise ValueError("passwords do not match")
        return v


try:
    UserModel(password1="abc", password2="xyz")
except ValidationError as err:
    print(err.json(indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
[
    {
        "loc": [
            "password2"
        ],
        "msg": "passwords do not match",
        "type": "value_error"
    }
]
```

---

### The new way (v2) using `@field_validator`

You would have to rewrite the v1 code above like this in v2:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError, ValidationInfo, field_validator


class UserModel(BaseModel):
    ...
    password1: str
    password2: str

    @field_validator("password2")
    def passwords_match(cls, v: str, info: ValidationInfo) -> str:
        if "password1" in info.data and v != info.data["password1"]:
            raise ValueError("passwords do not match")
        return v


try:
    UserModel(password1="abc", password2="xyz")
except ValidationError as err:
    print(err.json(indent=4))
```

v2 output:

```json
[
    {
        "type": "value_error",
        "loc": [
            "password2"
        ],
        "msg": "Value error, passwords do not match",
        "input": "xyz",
        "ctx": {
            "error": "passwords do not match"
        },
        "url": "https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/value_error"
    }
]
```

---

### Another way (v2) using an annotated validator

For the sake of completeness, Pydantic v2 offers a new way of validating fields, which is [annotated validators](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/validators/#annotated-validators). The above code could just as easily be written with for example an [`AfterValidator`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/functional_validators/#pydantic.functional_validators.AfterValidator) like this:

```py
from typing import Annotated

from pydantic import AfterValidator, BaseModel, ValidationError, ValidationInfo


def ensure_passwords_match(v: str, info: ValidationInfo) -> str:
    if "password1" in info.data and v != info.data["password1"]:
        raise ValueError("passwords do not match")
    return v


class UserModel(BaseModel):
    ...
    password1: str
    password2: Annotated[str, AfterValidator(ensure_passwords_match)]


try:
    UserModel(password1="abc", password2="xyz")
except ValidationError as err:
    print(err.json(indent=4))
```

The output is exactly the same as in the `@field_validator` example.

#### Background

As you can see from the Pydantic core API docs linked above, annotated validator constructors take the same type of argument as the decorator returned by `@field_validator`, namely either a [`NoInfoValidatorFunction`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic-core/blob/8db3a6f45b4af2e977a56af1f34099b8f5ff01eb/python/pydantic_core/core_schema.py#L1775) or a [`WithInfoValidatorFunction`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic-core/blob/8db3a6f45b4af2e977a56af1f34099b8f5ff01eb/python/pydantic_core/core_schema.py#L1784), so either a `Callable[[Any], Any]` or a `Callable[[Any, ValidationInfo], Any]`.

(Strictly speaking the signature of the `field_validator` inner decorator is different because it technically can deal with more nuances like implicit classmethods etc., but it is designed to essentially deal with the same type of functions.)

#### Key takeaway

Field-specific validator functions thus should always have either one parameter (the value to validate) or two (the value and the `ValidationInfo` object).

Comment: Perfect answer! S2